# Does it help to add fiber to sugary foods?

Tags: digestion, sugar, fibre

One of the problems with fruit juice is that it provides all the sugar with almost none of the fiber to help slow the absorption of sugar in the body.  If fiber is added back to the fruit juice before drinking, for example with ground flaxseed, does this help prevent the body from absorbing too much sugar?  (Keeping in mind that we are now learning that juicing is not actually so healthy.)

What about more generally eating fiber alongside sugary foods?  For example, eating raspberries or figs or almonds alongside a slice of cake?  Does this help slow the absorption of sugar from the cake to any noticeable degree?  (Not making the cake healthy per se, but does it help make it somewhat "less bad"?)

If this does help, why doesn't the food industry add more fiber to processed foods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short **yes**. Fiber reduces the postprandial blood sugar. It reduces both how much and how fast the blood sugar raises after a meal, as found in [this study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27571099).

Having high blood sugar, in turn, affects your health in several negative ways, such as

[image]

*By Chrizz, Glykemiskt Index (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Glykemiskt_Index.PNG) [[CC BY-SA 3.0]](http://articles.mercola.com/sugar-side-effects.aspx), via Wikimedia Commons*

However, the amount of calories consumed is still the same, so it does not help in that regard.

At any rate, sugar is overall [bad for your health](http://articles.mercola.com/sugar-side-effects.aspx), so staying away from it completely is still best, And it is not even that hard.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to find something about how blood sugar affect in turn, but did not find aynthing useful so far.

Comment: Like heck it's "not even that hard". The only non-sugary drinks you can find when eating out are nasty diet sodas, unsweetened ice tea, and water.

Comment: Dried fruits and white sugar are bad, whole grains are good -- so how about oatmeal raisin cookies? Are they "less bad"?

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson Water, wine? Sweet drinks drowns out the taste from most food imho. Kebab is an exceptions there I def need a coke. :-)

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson dried fruit very sweet, yes, but they also has lots of fiber, so relating to this specific question they are better than white sugar. What are you comparing oatmeal raisin cookies with? In general, check the sugar content (I also look for aspartam and stuff and avoid that), the less the better when it come to food. For desserts and so on, I personally don't worry so much. :-) But relating to this quetion, eating desserts after meals reduces the blood sugar spike. E.g. if you take a oatmeal rasin cookie in the afternoon, it'll make you more tired than taking it after dinner, etc.